# Position code independant executable on windows

Tags: portable-executable

Is it possible to build a position independant code for windows ?
I am not talking about a dll, i am talking about an executable (PE).

What i want to do is that functions (main for example) which are in the program should be mapped at a different memory address between 2 executions.

Thanks

Comment: yes, this is possible. and so what ?

Comment: how do you do this in visual studio ? Should a activate something on the target operating system ?

Comment: at first visual studio here absolute not related. all what need for this - enough knowledge. *Should a activate something on the target operating system* - of course no

Comment: There is nothing to do to enable ASLR ?

Comment: how aslr here related at all ?

Comment: if aslr is not enabled at os level, PIE won't work for executables ?

Comment: aslr have nothing common with base independed code at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up on the image base relocation directory in a PE file. I was wondering the same thing you are asking now a while back. From the research I had done I couldn't find any compiler that generates completely base independent code. I ended up writing my program entirely in x86 asm with some tricks to load strings etc independent form the address. I can tell you its not worth the trouble. Just remap all the addresses to your target location.

I suggest you start reading this
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx

You should also check out Icezilon's (not sure how you spell his name) tutorials. They're very helpful